# Laravel Eloquent search by multiple fields

Tags: php, laravel, search, eloquent

I want to search in database from user input.
Everything is working, but when I trying to find with PLD type, search query not giving me result that I expect.

[image]

Firmware field can by with two PLD types, for example Firmware: V49, PLD: A5 and A6. PLD type comes from hwtype and optional hwtype2 field, firmware comes from hw field.
This is my database:

[image]

My search function:

```
public function search(Request $request)
    {
      $dumpDb = Dumpdb::query();
      // Search values for select 
      $hw = Dumpdb::select('hw')->distinct()->get();
      $pld = Dumpdb::select('hwtype')->distinct()->get();

      // Search filters
      if ($request->has('hw') && $request->input('hw') != '') {
        $dumpDb = $dumpDb->where('hw', '=', $request->input('hw'));
      }

      if ($request->has('pld') && $request->input('pld') != '') {
        $dumpDb = $dumpDb->where('hwtype', $request->input('pld'))->orWhere('hwtype2', $request->input('pld'));
      }

      $countData = $dumpDb->count();
      $dumpDb = $dumpDb->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(30);


      return view('dumpDb.index', compact('hw', 'pld', 'dumpDb', 'countData', 'hwtype'));
    }
```

Comment: what do you expect and what's you currently getting??

Comment: For example user choose Firmware: B50 and PLD Type: A2, but for some reason I getting B50 and other Firmware version other than the user choice

Comment: as you are using orWhere its getting all data with firmware b50 and pld a2. you have to do it in a where closure.

Comment: But without orWhere my query not finding my records. I need to loop throw hwtype and hwtype2. For example I have same PLD type (A2) in some cases in hwtype and hwtype2, so I need all records from both of this tables.

Comment: i am adding an answer for you. check that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as you need filtering from both hw and hwtype you need two where clauses with the second with a closure. first where clause will filter hw and the second one will filter from hwtype with second level where clause. all that means like

```
if ($request->has('hw') && $request->input('hw') != '') {
    $dumpDb = $dumpDb->where('hw', '=', $request->input('hw'));
}

if ($request->has('pld') && $request->input('pld') != '') {
    $dumpDb = $dumpDb->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('hwtype', $request->input('pld'))
                  ->orWhere('hwtype2', $request->input('pld'));
        });
}
```